# Почему данная функция в GO при вводе в "1 1 1" не выдает ничего?

Tags: функции, golang

Почему данная функция в  GO при вводе в "1 1 1" не выдает ничего?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func SqRoots() {
    var a, b, c float64
    fmt.Scan(&a, &b, &c)
    D := math.Sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c)
    if D < 0 {
        fmt.Println("0 0")
    }
    if D == 0 {
        fmt.Println((-b + D) / 2 * a)
    }
    if D > 0 {
        fmt.Println((-b-D)/2*a, (-b+D)/2*a)
    }
}
func main() {
    SqRoots()
}
```

Comment: Потому что корень из отрицательного числа равен `NaN`

Comment: Спасибо большое!